# Converting / getting parametric equation to work using python

Tags: python, animation, bezier-curves, animation-nodes, mathematics

Converting / getting parametric equation to work in Python / Blender / Animation Nodes

I can create / plot the parametric equation in Octave

$$x=u\sin(u)\cos(v)$$
$$y=u\cos(u)\cos(v)$$
$$z=-u\sin(v)-\sin(60/180*\pi)*\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$$

Octave code:

```
clc
close all
clear all

u=linspace(0,4*pi,100);
v=linspace(0,pi,100);
[u,v]=meshgrid(u,v);
x=u.*sin(u).*cos(v);
y=u.*cos(u).*cos(v);
z=-u.*sin(v) .-  sin(60/180 * pi)*(sqrt((x).^2 + (y).^2));
figure(1)
mesh(x,y,z);
view([-57,32])
h=gca; 
get(h,'FontSize') 
set(h,'FontSize',14)
xlabel('X','fontSize',14);
ylabel('Y','fontSize',14);
zlabel('Z','fontsize',14);
title('3D Parametric Equation Lily impeller','fontsize',14)
fh = figure(1);
set(fh, 'color', 'white');
```

Octave Image it creates:
[image: Lily image]

But I'm having some issues converting that over to Python and Blender.
What I have so far is below.

```
import math
import numpy as np

def surf(u, v):

    x1 = u*math.sin(u)*math.cos(v)
    y1 = u*math.cos(u)*math.cos(v)
    z1 = u*math.sin(v) - math.sin(60/180 *math.pi) *math.sqrt((x1**2 + (y1)**2))
    return x1, y1, z1

ux, vx = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 4*math.pi, 100), np.linspace(0, math.pi, 100))
x1, y1, z1 = surf(ux, vx)


position1 = Vector((x1,y1,z1))
```

> One of the issues is with the line `x1, y1, z1 = surf(ux, vx)` gives me an error **TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars** I tried converting the line to `x1, y1, z1 = surf(np.vectorize(ux), np.vectorize(vx))` but that just gives me another error saying **it must be real number, not Vectorized**

Animation Nodes:
[image]

I plan on using animation nodes to animate it over time.

Comment: I'm not python or programming expert so forgive me if this doesn't make sense at all but could it be that you're trying to pass an array with the length of 3 to single axis values along x, y and z?



So your function returns 3 values along x, y and z. Then you're trying to pass an array value to 3 single non-array values.



Perhaps you could write another function called getPos( arrayOfSizeThree) which runs the surf(u, v) function and adds the new values to each axis. Then you could make new position arrays which run the getPos function. But I'm no expert haha

Comment: I'm not sure how this script work but reason for the error is obvious. ux and uy is a array of 100 values. you are trying to do surf() which contains math.sin, math.cos functions. Those functions can only perform single value at a time not list of values. you can either use a loop or change math.sin and math.cos to numpy function(np.sin and np.cos).

Comment: The `np.vectorize` is use on function not value or array. It will give you a vectorized  function to deal with array